# How to switch off storage IBM DS 3512?

Tags: storage, ibm

It is a very simple question...
How to switch off the storage (ex for maintance)?
I really don't know if there is a standard procedure to switch off a SAS storage. I did not find any switch to push and in Storage management software there is not any option to shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main system documentation - the [IBM System Storage DS3500 Implementation Guide](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247914.pdf) - has this text passage in section *4.9.2 - Powering on and off*:

> #### Powering off
>
> In normal circumstances, the DS3500 subsystem would rarely be powered off: it is designed
>   to run continuously. However, in certain events (scheduled maintenance, controller
>   replacement on a single controller subsystem, emergency due to unforeseen circumstances,
>   and so on), you will have to power the subsystem off. Use the same steps as above, but in the
>   reverse order. If you cannot shut down and power off the host servers, then make sure the
>   DS3500 logical drives are unmounted at the operating system level.
>   Note: For controller LED and other hardware information, refer to the appropriate System
>   Storage DS3500 Storage Subsystem: Installation, User's, and Maintenance Guide manual,
>   which can be found at the following URL.
>   http://www-304.ibm.com/systems/support/
>
> *Note:* A DS3500 subsystem that powers up with no drives installed will get a dummy
>   FEI. Also, the controllers are accessible through DS Storage Manager and new
>   (different) firmware can be loaded. This means that certain maintenance actions can be
>   taken. Drives can be re-added or powered up and the controllers will reboot to load
>   information out of the DACSTORE on the drives.
>
> **Important:** Unless it is an emergency, the DS3500 subsystem should never be turned off if
>   any amber LEDs are lit. You should use the Recovery Guru and other troubleshooting tools
>   to correct the failure first.

Basically, it boils down to this order:

1. shut down all serves using the storage
2. switch off the main unit (use the switches on the power supplies on the rear)
3. switch off the expansion enclosures, if any
4. switch off the storage switches

Answer (score 1):

So long as the server (and more importantly the filesystem) is had been gracefully shut down you can power off the disk shelf by simply removing the power cables.